# RabbitMQ .NET Core Client ManualResetEventSlim.Wait consuming a lot of cpu

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, cpu, hangfire, waithandle

I'm debugging a .net core 6 app in a docker container (I've used dotnet-trace tool) and I've notice that it gives me 30% oc cpu usage in the wait method of ManualResetEventSlim class used by the rabbitMQ.Client for .net core.

My question is how is that a "wait" is consuming a lot of cpu while it's doing "nothing", just waiting.

[image]

Can anyone help me understand what is happening under the hood with this "wait"? I've notice the same thing with the Hangfire postgress client

[image]

Most of the time spend on the WaitMultiple method, consuming cpu while waiting.

I understand the part where it's an infinite loop (while true maybe) like a web server that it's waiting for requests to be processed, what I don't understand is the cpu consumption.

Comment: This is a much better place to ask questions about the .NET client. Be sure to provide library version information and ideally, code to reproduce your issue - https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/discussions